# Sort by constructor ignoring (part of) value

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have

```
data Foo = A String Int | B Int
```

I want to take an `xs :: [Foo]` and sort it such that all the `A`s are at the beginning, sorted by their strings, but with the ints in the order they appeared in the list, and then have all the Bs at the end, in the same order they appeared.

In particular, I want to create a new list containg the first A of each string and the first B.

I did this by defining a function taking `Foo`s to `(Int, String)`s and using sortBy and groupBy.

Is there a cleaner way to do this? Preferably one that generalizes to at least 10 constructors.

Typeable, maybe? Something else that's nicer?

EDIT: This is used for processing a list of `Foo`s that is used elsewhere. There is already an Ord instance which is the normal ordering.

Comment: These requirements sound rather odd. Perhaps a change of data structure would be more appropriate?

Comment: Possibly. What would I change it to? Any data structure would still have to keep track of each constructor, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, but it seems to me like you might benefit from organizing your data differently. In particular, it sounds like you might want multiple lists instead of one here, but it's hard to say without more context. You could try posting your code on [codereview.se] to get some suggestions for how it might be improved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
sortBy (comparing foo)
```

where `foo` is a function that extracts the interesting parts into something comparable (e.g. `Int`s).

In the example, since you want the `A`s sorted by their `Strings`, a mapping to `Int` with the desired properties would be too complicated, so we use a compound target type.

```
foo (A s _) = (0,s)
foo (B _)   = (1,"")
```

would be a possible helper. This is more or less equivalent to Tikhon Jelvis' suggestion, but it leaves space for the natural `Ord` instance.

Comment: This is exactly what I did, but it becomes smelly as Foo gets more constructors.

Comment: True, but every special case gets smelly when enough entities to take care of are involved. The only thing that scales really well is `deriving Ord` (and that also only because you leave the smelly bits to the compiler).

Comment: Well, or some TH or Generics, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

To make it easier to build comparison function for ADTs with large number of constructors, you can map values to their constructor index with SYB:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Generics

data Foo = A String Int | B Int deriving (Show, Eq, Typeable, Data)

cIndex :: Data a => a -> Int
cIndex = constrIndex . toConstr
```

Example:

```
*Main Data.Generics> cIndex $ A "foo" 42
1
*Main Data.Generics> cIndex $ B 0
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit:After re-reading your question, I think the best option is to make `Foo` an instance of `Ord`. I do not think there is any way to do this automatically that will act the way you want (just using `deriving` will create different behavior).

Once `Foo` is an instance of `Ord`, you can just use `sort` from `Data.List`.

In your exact example, you can do something like this:

```
data Foo = A String Int | B Int deriving (Eq)

instance Ord Foo where
  (A _ _) <= (B _)    = True
  (A s _) <= (A s' _) = s <= s'
  (B _)   <= (B _)    = True
```

When something is an instance of `Ord`, it means the data type has some ordering. Once we know how to order something, we can use a bunch of existing functions (like `sort`) on it and it will behave how you want. Anything in `Ord` has to be part of `Eq`, which is what the `deriving (Eq)` bit does automatically.

You can also derive `Ord`. However, the behavior will not be exactly what you want--it will order by *all* of the fields if it has to (e.g. it will put `A`s with the same string in order by their integers).

Further edit: I was thinking about it some more and realized my solution is probably semantically wrong.

An `Ord` instance is a statement about your whole data type. For example, I'm saying that `B`s are always equal with each other when the derived `Eq` instance says otherwise.

If the data your representing *always* behaves like this (that is, `B`s are all equal and `A`s with the same string are all equal) then an `Ord` instance makes sense. Otherwise, you should *not* actually do this.

However, you can do something almost exactly like this: write your own special `compare` function (`Foo -> Foo -> Ordering`) that encapsulates exactly what you want to do then use `sortBy`. This properly codifies that your particular sorting is special rather than the natural ordering of the data type.

Comment: If there were a way to have implicit transitivity, that would work; otherwise, this becomes extremely boilerplate-y when I also have C, D, and E constructors, and the number of cases I need to write is quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some template haskell to fill in the missing transitive cases.  The `mkTransitiveLt` creates the transitive closure of the given cases (if you order them least to greatest).  This gives you a working less-than, which can be turned into a function that returns an `Ordering`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import MkTransitiveLt
import Data.List (sortBy)

data Foo = A String Int | B Int | C | D | E deriving(Show)

cmp a b = $(mkTransitiveLt [|
  case (a, b) of
    (A _ _, B _)    -> True
    (B _,   C)      -> True
    (C,     D)      -> True
    (D,     E)      -> True
    (A s _, A s' _) -> s < s'
    otherwise       -> False|])

lt2Ord f a b =
  case (f a b, f b a) of
    (True, _) -> LT
    (_, True) -> GT
    otherwise -> EQ

main = print $ sortBy (lt2Ord cmp) [A "Z" 1, A "A" 1, B 1, A "A" 0, C]
```

Generates:

```
[A "A" 1,A "A" 0,A "Z" 1,B 1,C]
```

`mkTransitiveLt` must be defined in a separate module:

```
module MkTransitiveLt (mkTransitiveLt)
where

import Language.Haskell.TH

mkTransitiveLt :: ExpQ -> ExpQ
mkTransitiveLt eq = do
  CaseE e ms <- eq
  return . CaseE e . reverse . foldl go [] $ ms
    where
      go ms m@(Match (TupP [a, b]) body decls) = (m:ms) ++
        [Match (TupP [x, b]) body decls | Match (TupP [x, y]) _ _ <- ms, y == a]
      go ms m = m:ms
```